# How to pass custom data types on page navigate in flutterflow?

Tags: flutterflow

While defining the parameter on the landing page, there is no option to select a custom data type already created and used in the project.

Current use case - navigating from a list of custom data types to viewing the details on the guided page.

Passing the index of the clicked item is an option, but mapping each item inside the details page is tedious and repetitive.

I have passed the index as a variable to the new page and then ran a query on each variable to get the list item and map value. But this is not efficient.